# C# MySQL Error: Keyword not supported

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem with my writting to database and reading from database.

Here is my code:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
string ID = "";
MySqlCommand cmdRegister = new MySqlCommand("Insert into Players (username,password) values('"+"John"+"', '"+"johnisbest"+"')", conn);
cmdRegister.ExecuteNonQuery();
MySqlCommand cmdRead = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM Players WHERE username = '"+this.username+"';", conn);
MySqlDataReader reader = cmdRead.ExecuteReader();
conn.Open();

while (reader.Read())
{
    ID = (string)reader["ID"];
}
conn.Dispose();
return ID;
```

It give me always error: Keyword not supported

Thanks for every help ;)

EDIT:

```
public MySQL(string IPaddress, string port, string username, string password, string database)
{
    ConnectionString = "datasource=" + IPaddress + ";port=" + port + ";username=" + username + ";password=" + password + ";database=" + database + ";charse=utf_8";
}
sql = new MySQL("IP address to database", "3306", "username to database", "Here is my password to database", "name of my database");
```

Comment: Password is a [Reserved Word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Esacpe it with back ticks.  You should not be storing passwords as plain text

Comment: use pwd instead of password like the way defined here https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: I would also suggest that you learn to use `Parameters as well as string.Format() Function vs the concatenated strings to build your connection string. do the same with your Select Statement do not use concatenated string...!

Answer (score 0):

```
 ConnectionString = "datasource=" + IPaddress + ";port=" + port + ";username=" + username + ";pwd=" + password + ";database=" + database + ";charse=utf_8";
```

Tried to replace password with "pwd";

for me this work fine

```
Server=localhost;Database=testing;UID=root;password=testing;connect timeout=700;charset=utf8;pooling=true;Port=3306
```

Comment: @Dortík Which version you are using?

Comment: I using version 4.5